# Referencing(?) problem with windows in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

--EDIT--
I have got a welcome window consisting of two JLabels. It has a link to a timer counting from 3 to 0. After that time, a new window, "UsedBefore", containing JLabel and radio buttons should automatically appear in the place of the previous one. When I run the "Launcher", the first window shows up with counter displaying 3,2,1,0 and then nothing happens.

I think the problem lies in poor referencing, but I'm not sure. I've got "Launcher" class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Welcome window = new Welcome();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

} // end main
```

Where I launch the "Welcome" window:

```
public Welcome() {
    init();
}

public void init() {

    // here I'm adding stuff to the window and then I have:     

    setLayout(cardLayout);
    add(big, "1welcome");
//  UsedBefore.MakeUsedBeforeWindow(); // ???
    new MyTimer(this).start();

} // end init
```

this goes to MyTimer which does the countdown and:

```
 welcome.showNextWindow(); // private Welcome welcome;
```

we go back to the "Welcome" class:

```
public void showNextWindow() {
    cardLayout.next(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Welcome());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(550, 450);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and finally the "UsedBefore" class:

```
public UsedBefore() {           
        super(new BorderLayout());
        init();         
    }

    public void MakeUsedBeforeWindow() {            

        String q = "Have you used GUI before?";
        JPanel area = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(area, "2usedBefore?");
        area.setBackground(Color.white);
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">"
                + q + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
        Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 30);
        textLabel.setFont(font);
        textLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 250, 0)); //top, left, bottom, right
        area.add(textLabel, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        add(area, "2usedBefore?");          
    }
```

with its main:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane - not sure how to do it
//          JComponent newContentPane = new UsedBefore();
//          newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
//          frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
//          frame.getContentPane().add(new UsedBefore());

        //Display the window.
        frame.setSize(550, 450);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

That's quite a journey. Sorry for a lot of code, I hope the path is clear. Once I've got 1->2->3 links right, I should be able to do the rest of them, so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the question? (found one in the title) :)

Comment: I'm assuming that is bad referencing. If so, how should I do a good one? ;) If not, what is the actual problem?

Comment: @Hurdler: Good question :-) what is the actual problem?

Comment: I guess I messed up the "path" and windows don't show up.

Comment: @Hrdler, your question is unclear. You posted a lot of code but have not explained almost anything. Try to minimize the code and ask clear question. Most likely if question may be asked without knowing details of your application and without running your code. It is possible. Just try again. And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: Ok, I thought you need to see the code (it's already been reduced significantly) in order to spot what's wrong. I will edit my question adding more explanation.

Comment: The code fragments are still confusing -- in which class is the `welcome` variable held? If you can remove the commented out code as well as the code that's setting up the gui, and expand on what the MyTimer class does, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different approach. Why not building `JPanel` instead of Windows and adding/removing these `JPanel` at the desire time.

Ex (here `welcome` panel is shown first with its decreasing counter and when the counter reach 0, `other` panel is shown):

```
public class T extends JFrame {

private int couterValue = 3;
private JPanel welcome;
private JLabel counter;

private JPanel other;
private Timer timer;

public T() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    buildWelcomePanel();
    buildOtherPanel();

    add(welcome);
    setSize(550, 450);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (couterValue == 0) {
                timer.cancel();
                // Switch the panels as the counter reached 0
                remove(welcome);
                add(other);
                validate();
            } else {
                counter.setText(couterValue + ""); // Update the UI counter
                couterValue--;
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);

}

private void buildWelcomePanel() {
    welcome = new JPanel();
    counter = new JLabel();
    welcome.add(counter);
}

private void buildOtherPanel() {
    other = new JPanel();
    JLabel otherStuff = new JLabel("Anything else ...");
    other.add(otherStuff);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new T();
}
}
```